# import behaviour in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have a doubt regarding import statement in python.
Here is my `functions.py` file

```py
week_days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
             "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]


def get_week_day(day_no: int):
    return week_days[day_no % 7]
```

and `testing .py`:

```py
from functions import get_week_day

print(get_week_day(100))
```

And the output is `Tuesday`.
In my `testing.py` file I am only importing `get_week_day` function from `functions.py` but still the function is able to access the array `week_days`. How...?

Please explain this.

Answer (score 2):

as you can read [on this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471) `from functions import get_week_day`  **still imports the whole Module**. So it seems logic that since `def get_week_day(day_no: int):` refers to `week_days`, it accesses `week_days` from the imported module.
Reading  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) might solve any further doubts on this matter.

Comment: More importantly, `get_week_day` contains a reference to its global scope, which is why `week_days` refers to `functions.week_days`, not `testing.week_days`.